# WooCommerce CSS help in changing size of order note input box

Tags: css, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to change the height size of the 'Add Note" input box in WooCommerce admin edit orders page

- screenshot below:

[image]

I constantly have to resize this box and I would like the height to be approx 200 px instead of 50.

The element is
textarea#add_order_note.input-text

```
.add_note #add_order_note {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
}
```

I am hoping someone might be able to advise the correct CSS code I need to enter via Appearance - Customize - Additional CSS or perhaps I should be using a code snippet ?

I have made a few different CSS attempts, but I don't know how to input the code correctly

Comment: ok - the box I want to adjust is on the admin side tho.....

Comment: Are you trying to change the UI of the woocommerce add-on in Wordpress?

Comment: I am trying to change the height size of the 'Add Note" input box in woocommerce admin edit orders page - is that not possible ?

Comment: Before I can answer that, I need an answer on my question. UI means User Interface. The input box's appearance is part of the UI. 

Are you using woocommerce with Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
Add this to your functions theme.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'customcss');

function customcss() {
  echo '<style>
    #add_order_note {height: 200px !important;}
  </style>';}
```

Comment: I think where I am putting the code only affects the front end store - not admin area  perhaps.

Comment: @yatgirl You're right. I had to use a function to add the css into the admin css. I test it and it works.

Comment: this post wont let me edit the code. I found that with the original code - the box was not resizeable with the box bottom little corner pull.  I changed the code "(height to "(min-height and the box is now resizeable if it is needed to be larger.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code snippet to your active theme `functions.php`

```
/**
 * Add styling to wc admin
 */
function wc_order_styles_update() {

    $custom_css = "
                .add_note #add_order_note{
                        height: 300px !important;
                }";
    wp_add_inline_style('woocommerce_admin_styles', $custom_css);
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wc_order_styles_update');
```

Tested OK with **WooCommerce 6.3**. Adding the style override to an existing style sheet can be done using the WP standard function [wp_add_inline_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/)

`admin_enqueue_scripts` is the proper hook to use when [enqueuing scripts and styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) that are meant to be used in the administration panel. Despite the name, it is used for enqueuing both scripts and styles.

Answer (score 0):

In css:

```
textarea#add_order_note {
 width:100%;
 height: 200px;
 resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this is a change you want to persist through plugin updates, theme updates, etc. It should be made within the CSS file of your child theme. If you're unsure what I mean by that, I highly recommend you read up on using a child theme before any continued development. There is [a tutorial from Woocommerce](https://woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/) about this as well, besides [those found on Wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Another alternative is a plugin designed for CSS alteration, i.e. Jetpack, as mentioned in the [Woocommerce Best Practices Documentation](https://woocommerce.com/document/customizing-woocommerce-best-practices/).

While there are many ways to accomplish this, adding a snippet into your `functions.php` isn't ideal from a design and maintainability perspective. That should be reserved for logical (functional, business logic, whatever term you choose) changes, rather than layout (view, display, etc) changes. Wordpress is built on the principles of MVC and it's best to maintain that logical separation of code whenever possible. Even in "Appearance - Customize - Additional CSS" is better than in `functions.php` - although I prefer to avoid using that altogether, as it can quickly become cluttered and difficult to maintain.